# Uploading files to parse keep restarting and then fail?

Tags: android, parse-platform

please help I'm stuck for four days in that problem!
I'm trying to upload pdf files to parse, but it restarting when it reach 100% and after some tries failing and give that exception:

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

but it sometimes working for some files.

there is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent choosePhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                choosePhotoIntent.setType("pdf/*");
                startActivityForResult(choosePhotoIntent, 1);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() returned: ");
                Uri pdfUri = data.getData();
                byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(this, pdfUri);
                //replace spaces with "_" because parse don't   accept file name with spaces.
                String fileName = pdfUri.getLastPathSegment().replaceAll("\\s+", "_");

                Log.d(TAG, "pdf uri: " + pdfUri);
                Log.d(TAG, "pdf fileName: " + fileName);


                ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("bigPdf");

                ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("fileName", fileBytes);
                parseObject.put("pdf", parseFile);

                parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "done ");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "done: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                }, new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "done " + percentDone);
                    }
                });


                parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "done ");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "done: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After five days of tries and failed it turns out that it's a bug in parse SDK introduced in version 1.4.2 and stayed since then, so I have reported it to them.

so until they fix that bug I used version 1.4.1 and it works, but the progress indicator seems that it was compleated in version 1.5 so it gives you 100% and nothing before. but at least uploading is working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to save the parse object after the file is saved, so it would look like this:

```
                final ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("bigPdf");

                ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("fileName", fileBytes);
                parseObject.put("pdf", parseFile);

                parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "done ");

                            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "done ");
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "done: ", e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "done: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                }, new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "done " + percentDone);
                    }
                });
```

There may be other problems but it looks like that's where to start.

Comment: what is the difference between my code and yours! the same problem with your code.

Comment: Your code doesn't wait for the file save operation to complete before saving the parse object.  Mine moves the parse object save into the file save callback.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand from the first time but the parse SDK handle it itself and waits for the file to be saved before saving the Object. so it's that problem at all; anyway I tried your code and the problem the same, so it's a bug in the SDK because when I used older one as I describe in my answer my problem is solved.

any way thanks